# DCT in a proof of (vague) portmanteau theorem over locally compact metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $(X,d)$ be a locally compact metric space and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the Borel sets. Let $\mu_n,\mu:\mathscr{B}\to [0,\infty]$ be regular measures over $(X,\mathscr{B})$. We say $\mu_n$ converges vaguely  to $\mu$ (or $\mu_n \stackrel{\textrm{v}}{\to}\mu$) if $\int_Xud\mu_n\to \int_Xud\mu$ for all compactly supported continuous $u$ (i.e. $u \in C_c(X))$.

As part of a proof of a portmanteau theorem, I read that
$$\mu_n(B)\to\mu(B),\,\forall B \in \mathscr{B}\textrm{ relatively compact s.t. }\mu(\partial B)=0\implies\mu_n \stackrel{\textrm{v}}{\to}\mu$$
In the proof of this passage, it is first shown that $\{t>0:\mu(\partial\{u\geq t\})>0\}$ has Lebesgue measure zero. Then, a DCT is applied as following
$$\begin{aligned}\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{(0,\infty)}\mu_n\{u\geq t\}dt&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{(0,\|u\|_\infty)}\mu_n\{u\geq t\}dt\color{red}{\stackrel{(?)}{=}}\\
&=\int_{(0,\|u\|_\infty)}\lim_{n \to \infty}\mu_n\{u\geq t\}dt=\\
&=\int_{(0,\|u\|_\infty)}\mu\{u\geq t\}dt\end{aligned}$$
While the rest seems to me clear, I do not understand the $\color{red}{(?)}$ passage and how DCT has been applied. For example, if $M:=\sup_n\mu_n(X)<\infty$ we would have
$$\mu_n\{u\geq t\}\mathbf{1}_{(0,\|u\|_\infty)}(t)\leq M\mathbf{1}_{(0,\|u\|_\infty)}(t)\in L^1(dt)$$
and we could use DCT and take the limit over $\{t>0:\mu(\partial\{u\geq t\})=0\}$. However, I don't see how DCT is used seemingly without assumptions on $\mu_n$ with the exception of regularity. Is $(X,d)$ being locally compact involved here? Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regular measures are finite on compact sets. Note that $\{x: u(x) >t\}$ is  a subset of  the support $K$ of $u$. We can choose an open set $U$ such that $K  \subseteq U \subseteq \overline U$ and  $\overline U$ is compact. Further we can choose $U$ to be a $\mu-$ continuity set. It now follows that $\mu_n (\{x: u(x)>t\})\leq \mu_n (K) \leq \mu_n (\overline U) \to \mu (\overline U)<\infty$. Hence, DCT can be applied.

Comment: Hello @geetha290krm thank you! Just a question: why can we be sure that such $U$ exists?

Comment: It is by local compactness. You can choose $U$ of the form $\{x: d(x,K) <r\}$. @Snoop

Comment: Ok! What about $\mu(\partial U)=0$? Is it also guaranteed by local compactness? (Sorry for being pedantic)

Comment: $\mu (\partial \{x:d(x,K)<r\})=0$ for all but countably many values of $r$. This has to be combined with local compactness to obtain $U$. @Snoop

Comment: @geetha290krm Hi I have the same question and I am really having difficulty understanding here. Why is $\mu(\partial\{x:d(x,K)<r\})=0$ for all but countably many $r$? And what do you mean combine this with local compactness to obtain $U$.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician $\partial \{x: d(x,K)<r\}\subseteq \{x: d(x,K)=r\}$ and the sets  $\{x: d(x,K)=r\}$, $r>0$ are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @geetha290krm But how do we get relative compactness?

Comment: @nomadicmathematician For each point $x$ of $K$ there is an open set $U_x$ such that $x \in U_x$ and $\overline {U_x}$ is compact. Choose  a finite subcover for $K$ and take the union of those finite number of neighborhoods.

Comment: @geetha290krm Right I thought about that but I couldn't show that $d(x,K)<r$ belongs to the union of the open sets or balls. It seems obvious but hard to show. Any idea on how we can prove that?

Comment: Instead of $\{x:d(x,K) <r\}$ work with $\{x\in  U: d(x,K) <r\}$. Then you are already inside  a compact set. @nomadicmathematician